# Query user session length on a timestamped activity log

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrofit some analytics on a customer's MySQL 5.5 table.

Given a simple but large table:  `| user_id | timestamp |`

A `session_length` is defined as the longest number of minutes without an hour of idle time.

When I run some SQL query, I get `user_id`, `session_length` for each span of time a user is using the system without an hour of idleness.

Example table:

```
1 | 01:10
1 | 01:11
1 | 01:12
1 | 01:13
1 | 01:14
1 | 01:15
              ...
1 | 03:59
              ...
1 | 12:10
1 | 12:20
1 | 12:30
1 | 12:40
1 | 12:50
```

Should result in:

```
user_id | session_length
1       | 5
1       | 1
1       | 40
```

I'm not worried about time delta granularity.

I found a hint that this is dealt with in other db's with `LAG` functions. No such luck in MySQL.

Comment: so, You are looking for something like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql ? :-)

Comment: I don't know if I am or am not.  I suspect that I am.

Comment: `LAG` and other "Windowing functions" exist in MariaDB 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

Plan A:

1. Create a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` PK, plus the 2 columns in question.  (It can't be a `TEMPORARY` table due to an unfortunate limitation.)
2. Do a "self-join" to pair up adjacent rows.  Put this (id, user, and pair of times) in another table.
3. Filter -- keep pairs that are more than 1 hour.  (Need to also keep first and last times; this may involve `UNION`.)
4. Subtract adjacent `id` pairs to get `session_length`.  (This probably involves another table and another `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but could be done with an @variable.)  (Note:  Be aware of `auto_increment_increment`; if it is not 1, the subtract will be 'wrong'.)

So, Yes, it can be done in SQL; but do you want to go to this much work?

Plan B:  Somehow use @variables to count the session_length, watch out for change in userid, test for 1 hour, etc.

Plan C:  Migrate to MariaDB 10.2 and use its Windowing Functions.

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 - still developer version, not sure is it correct migrate production server to it? (Same as MySQL 8 which already people start recommend as answers). It is very risky even when it will be first GA but not RC. May be best plan B, Plan A think possible realise with subqueries as well, but it could work Slow with big data-sets

Comment: Agree -- don't put in production until GA.  But, if timing is right, you could start testing pre-release version.

Comment: Subqueries for Plan A?  Probably would need to have the same subquery twice.  Without CTEs (10.2 / 8.0), that gets messy.

Comment: agree - it will be really hard query, I just personally always follow simple rule - production we start use at least after 6 months from first GA, it help avoid a lot of trouble in production environment, when You have many servers and do not know from which part of code next problem come :)